# Emacs untagged agenda items in org-agenda

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How I can find the agenda items which are not tagged in org-agenda mode?
If I use the filtering option org-agenda-filter-by-tag (/ -  or C=u /) I have to exclude one by one all tags to achieve this and that is not what I want exactly.

Comment: You have 3 choices in `org-mode` to generate an `*Org Agenda*` buffer.  `M-x org-tags-view` or `M-x org-search-view` or `M-x org-agenda-list`.  The variable `org-agenda-custom-commands` is used by many people because it makes it easier to utilize the above-mentioned.  To read more about the functions, type `M-x describe-function`.  To read more about searches, read the advanced-search page from the manual:  http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html  You can also use `org-occur` within the `org-mode` flat file -- which is a method of folding non-relevant search criteria.

Comment: Related: [Orgmode: agenda for headlines without any tag](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18634/orgmode-agenda-for-headlines-without-any-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the special property TAGS:

TAGS=""

will match headlines with no tags.

See http://orgmode.org/org.html#Special-properties.

Comment: Thanks, This makes it easy for me discover and then tag the items.

Answer (score 0):

As for people who make heavy use of tag inheritance [1]
you may want to only display headlines without any kind of tags, excluding also those with inherited tags.

You can do so by using the special property ALLTAGS,
in the same way, as NickD pointed out:

ALLTAGS=""

[1] Tag inheritance
https://orgmode.org/org.html#Tag-Inheritance